# Chrome warns of data breach re password. Can I turn this off for selected domains?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm getting the following warning from Chrome when I enter certain user names/passwords into a form:

[image]

I want to have this feature on but I'm also testing an authentication function on a site I'm developing locally on my machine and so I'm wondering if it is possible to suppress this warning for certain domains (such as `localhost` etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this alert message:

1. Launch the Chrome browser on your machine.
2. Click on the vertical 3-dots icon situated at the top right and
   select the Settings menu.
3. Switch to the Privacy and Security tab, and click on Security.
4. Disable the Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach
   toggle to stop the alert.